# How Can I Populate a Simple Shopping Cart from Two MySQL Databases?

Tags: php, mysql, database, shopping-cart, populate

I am developing a simple PHP shopping cart and overall it is going well.  The difficulty that I am having is in being able to pull data from two separate databases in order to populate the fields of the shopping cart (unit price, name, quantities, etc...).

Here is the showCart function:

```
function showCart() {
global $db;
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
if ($cart) {
    $items = explode(',',$cart);
    $contents = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
    }
    $output[] = '<form action="cart.php?action=update" method="post" id="cart">';
    $output[] = '<table>';
    foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty) {

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id ='. $id;
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch();
        extract($row);
        $output[] = '<tr>';
        $output[] = '<td><a href="cart.php?action=delete&id='.$id.'" class="r">Remove</a></td>';
        $output[] = '<td>'.$product_name.' by '.$country.'</td>';
        $output[] = '<td>&#36;'.$price.'</td>';
        $output[] = '<td><input type="text" name="qty'.$id.'" value="'.$qty.'" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>';
        $output[] = '<td>&#36;'.($price * $qty).'</td>';
        $total += $price * $qty;
        $output[] = '</tr>';
    }
    $output[] = '</table>';
    $output[] = '<p>Grand total: <strong>&#36;'.$total.'</strong></p>';
    $output[] = '<div><button type="submit">Update cart</button></div>';
    $output[] = '</form>';
} else {
    $output[] = '<p>You shopping cart is empty.</p>';
}
return join('',$output);
}
```

The cart works fine as it is shown above. You can see that I have pulled the id, price, product name and a few other bits from the MySQL database table.  Now, I would like to make the price come from a different database table.  To do this, I tried the following...

First, I created a new connection which will get the price value I am after (Get_Price.php):

```
include 'connect.php';

$actual_price='_POST['new_price']';

$offer_price = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die ("Unable to connect to server");
mysql_select_db("$database", $offer_price) or die ("Unable to select database");

$get_value=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM offers WHERE actual_price = '$actual_price'");

$value_rslt = $db->query($get_value);
        $vlu_row = $value_rslt->fetch();
        extract($vlu_row);

        $vlu_otp[] = '<td>&#36;'.$special_offer.'</td>';
        $vlu_otp[] = '<td><input type="text" name="qty'.$unique_id.'" value="'.$qty.'" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>';
        $vlu_otp[] = '<td>&#36;'.($special_offer * $qty).'</td>';
        $total += $special_offer * $qty;
        $vlu_otp[] = '</tr>';
```

Then I used this call:

```
        include 'Get_Price.php';
```

as a substitute in the original code:

```
    function showCart() {
global $db;
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
if ($cart) {
    $items = explode(',',$cart);
    $contents = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
    }
    $output[] = '<form action="cart.php?action=update" method="post" id="cart">';
    $output[] = '<table>';
    foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty) {

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id ='. $id;
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch();
        extract($row);
        $output[] = '<tr>';
        $output[] = '<td><a href="cart.php?action=delete&id='.$id.'" class="r">Remove</a></td>';
        $output[] = '<td>'.$product_name.' by '.$country.'</td>';

        $output[] = '<td><input type="text" name="qty'.$id.'" value="'.$qty.'" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>';

        include 'Get_Price.php';
} else {
    $output[] = '<p>You shopping cart is empty.</p>';
}
return join('',$output);
}
```

This created a ton of errors and it dropped all the values.  What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try and see if you could use a single database for this.

If not, take a look at `Get_Price.php`. You are trying to connect to the second database here and use the variable `$offer_price` for it. But, when you are running the query against the second database, you are using `$db->query($get_value);` which will actually run against the first database.

Solution: Create two database connections in `connect.php` - something like `$db_cart` and `$db_price`. Then proceed as usual using the relevant connection. The rest of your code seems fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ultimately I did like you said and got everything into a single database and it worked out.